# Browser support list about `form[name]` feature

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, cross-browser

I have a code that uses [`form[name]` feature of `HtmlFormElement`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element), which is written by another person.

> form[name]
>
> Returns the form control (or, if there are several, a RadioNodeList of the form controls) in the form with the given ID or name (excluding image buttons for historical reasons); or, if there are none, returns the img element with the given ID.
>
> ...

Today, I am reported that the code seems to produce run time errors around there in specific web browsers.
I suspect that some web browser does not support `form[name]` feature.

Is there any list that tells which web browser support the feature?
I've tried to find on MDN and caniuse site, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: That existed in DOM Level 1 already … I think you should not be able to find _any_ browser that does not generally support this in the wild. (Certain actual names might be problematic maybe, if they collide with internal objects a certain browser provides around that.)

Comment: Thanks. I've found [this page](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#changed-apis), which might be regarding to `form[name]`, do you know what's the actual difference of it?
> elements on HTMLFormElement now returns an HTMLFormControlsCollection of button, fieldset, input, keygen, object, output, select and textarea elements. length returns the number of nodes in elements.

Comment: Can’t imagine they would make such a change in a way it breaks existing code; plus it still explicitly mentions the `element = collection[name]` syntax here, https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#htmlformcontrolscollection

Comment: what are the run time errors? Are you sure they're caused by the form[name] syntax compatibility? If you're still worry about compatibility problems, you can use more common 'document.querySelector' syntax.